# React hook useContext re-render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using global hooks with useContext to store signed up user information. I don't know why useContext render my component twice and state is undefined in the second time.
Provider is global, in the index.js

Any idea to prevent render twice the component?

store.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

const initialState = {
  accessToken: '',
  expirationDate: '',
  fullName: ''
};
const store = createContext(initialState);
const { Provider } = store;

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case 'login':
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        ...payload
      };
      return newState;
    default:
      throw new Error();
    }
  }, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export { store, StateProvider };
```

when i use useContext(store) i get this result:

[useContext result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8YP.png)

Comment: How many times your reducer is executed ?

Comment: that is! reducer execute twice, for the token expiration thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

## Don't default to error

Always return state in your reducer, not undefined. This is the first issue I see.

```
default:
  throw new Error();
}
```

to

```
default:
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that!